# React Router Dom Route Conditional Rendering

Tags: reactjs, web, react-router-dom

I trie to render a certain route if a token is valid , previously set when logging in , if not valid i redirect the user to the home page. But when i compile it kept showing a blank page. The registered token aims at protecting routes , so when user who was not logged in can't access the '/auth' endpoint.

Here is the code :

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to include a [mcve]. In other words, there should be a properly formatted and readable code snippet instead of pictures of code. Images are not accessible and can be more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a change in `cookies`, React would not be informed, hence your component will not be rendered to render the right `Route`. A React component only updates when its props or states changes, or the parent component renders it directly.

You can listen to cookies and set a state to notify React that cookies has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for this problem and it works fine actually.

Code :

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to paste the actual code here rather than just an image?